# How is `aicbic` or other matlab function used to find the AR order of specific data?

Tags: matlab, autoregressive-model

let us consider following matlab code

```
help aicbic
 aicbic Akaike and Bayesian information criteria

  Syntax:

    [aic,bic] = aicbic(logL,numParam,numObs)

  Description:

    Given optimized log-likelihood function values logL obtained by fitting
    a model to data, compute the Akaike (AIC) and Bayesian (BIC)
    information criteria. Since information criteria penalize models with
    additional parameters, aic and bic select models based on both goodness
    of fit and parsimony. When using either AIC or BIC, models that
    minimize the criteria are preferred.

  Input Arguments:

    logL - Vector of optimized log-likelihood objective function values
      associated with parameter estimates of various models.

    numParam - Number of estimated parameters associated with each value 
      in logL. numParam may be a scalar applied to all values in logL, or a 
      vector the same length as logL. All elements of numParam must be 
      positive integers.

  Optional Input Argument:

    numObs - Sample sizes of the observed data associated with each 
      value of logL. numObs is required for computing BIC, but not AIC.
      numObs may be a scalar applied to all values in logL, or a vector the
      same length as logL. All elements numObs must be positive integers. 

  Output Arguments:

    aic - Vector of AIC statistics associated with each logL objective
      function value. The AIC statistic is defined as:

        aic = -2*logL + 2*numParam

    bic - Vector of BIC statistics associated with each logL objective
      function value. The BIC statistic is defined as:

        bic = -2*logL + numParam*log(numObs)
```

Let us suppose that we have the data in a `matlab` vector `X`.

How do I  apply this matlab function (`aicbic`) to `X`?

I am trying to find the AR order of the data.

Comment: PLease stop posting your data all over the place. It's not instructive and will not help answer your question.

Comment: why?i have posted question 1000  times and always you are answering?can you give me complete answer? or?question is  exact right?so i need exact answer

Comment: i am asking,i have given signal,please help me to choose correct AR order using matlab,is it impossible?

Comment: i have asked absolutely concrete question:given signal data,using AIC abd BIC find AR model,we have matlab right?just what parameters and input i should use?just one word instead of theoretical explanation and useless answers,just one concrete example  and answer is it  impossible?how many hours i am trying to get help from this site and no result

Comment: ok i will delete my question

Comment: I am sorry that you are not getting the answers that you want from the site.  The answer is reasonably straightforward, it relies on figuring out what the likelihood function is for your estimation problem.

Comment: because it is easy for expierenced people to answer my question,how many hours i am posting similar questions to get answer and no result

Comment: @Peter.K do you know answer to my question let say honestly ok?

Comment: let say i dont know how to apply matlab code to given signal,somebody used it right?nobody is there that they can answer me?how to use function aicbic in matlab for given signal?is it difficult ?nobody used it in the world?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.mathworks.nl/help/econ/choose-arma-lags.html

Comment: but i dont know parameters of  AR model

Comment: Yes, I understand.  I've posed your question in a way that I think will get the answer you want.  I'm hoping that someone will be able to answer it quickly.  If not, I will try to answer it for you later tonight (my time). I'll have to derive it from first principles, so it'll take me a while. See the new question here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15326/can-someone-show-the-details-of-how-to-apply-aic-for-ar-models-to-specific-data

Comment: if i assign parameters my self,then how it could be effective?

Comment: @MattL. Nice one! Didn't come across that in my googling (though I've been trying to get the question into a form that's more relevant to the site than just matlab help).

Comment: @PeterK. I hope the OP appreciates your time and effort :)

Comment: no no,i understand  that he is helping me,but about link,should i indicate parameters my self?or  in my case,how it would be?

Comment: you should check aictest command for finding order which is applied before AR. In the example aicbic or bic is applied to chose the better AR model.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what the OP is asking for, but I have made an attempt to answer the question I wrote up (and referenced) earlier in this thread: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/15327/80